# How to get numerical value (PHP/Wordpress)

Tags: php, numerical

I don't know why but I can't get any numerical value from the following code.

```
   $key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Begin', true);
   $Begin = do_shortcode('[countup date='.$key_1_value.'][timer][/countup]');
   $Nombre = intval($Begin);
   echo $Begin;
   echo $Nombre;
```

echo $Begin give me something like "34 days"

echo $nombre give me "0"

I think it's because for it it's not a numerical value. I can't explain why. Is there a way to get "34" as a numerical value ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same format for `$Begin` then this should work fine:

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Begin', true);
$Begin = do_shortcode('[countup date='.$key_1_value.'][timer][/countup]');
$Nombre = (int) substr($Begin, 0, strpos($Begin, ' '));
echo $Begin;
echo $Nombre;
```

What I've changed is the third row where we remove everything after the space and typecast the rest of the string to an integer.

Comment: When you run my code, what does $Begin and $Nombre look like?

Comment: Still the same : $Begin: 34 Days $ Nombre: 0

Comment: I'm sure your code is fine for general value but maybe do_shortcode('[countup date='.$key_1_value.'][timer][/countup]'); can't be numerical even if I get 34 DAYS?

Comment: Well, in your question you stated that `$Begin` was (string) "34 days". If that's not the case then the problem is obviously some code before that which I wrote. Then please update your question to reflect the actual values of the variables after execution. If `$Begin` does have the value (string) "34 days" then my answer helps you.

Comment: OK. Sorry my english is not so good. echo $Begin give me "34 DAYS" and not (string) $Begin

Comment: No problem. Try this then: `preg_match("/(\\d+)/u", $Begin, $matches);
$Nombre = $matches[1];`

Comment: $key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Begin', true);
$Begin = do_shortcode('[countup date='.$key_1_value.'][timer][/countup]');
$Begin = preg_match("/(\\d+)/u", $Begin, $matches); $Nombre = $matches[1];
echo $Begin;
echo $Nombre;

It give me : 115799346

Comment: When I refresh the page the number is never the same :/